# How to set a paragraph to height of the bottom margin of the paragraph?

Tags: css, html

If a paragraph height is 70px then paragraph shows top of paragraph margin height. i want to display the paragraph bottom of paragraph height. it's may add css style. which property can I use to show a paragraph at the bottom of the paragraph height?

`<p style="height:70px">paragraph</p>` displays my text at the bottom of the element.

Comment: You mean, starting the text at the bottom of the `<p>` container?

Comment: Mind showing us your code?

Comment: <p style="height:70px">paragraph</p>. shows top of the height. wants bottom of the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: bottom`.

```css
p {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;  
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>

<p>paragraph</p>
```

Comment: it is ok. but, i need to display property value inline-block. i can't change display property. how i got this.

Comment: And *why* do you need it to be inline block?

Comment: thanks. i change my code. I use a parent div and use inline-block display. thanks so much.